# How to count groups of certain value in a numpy 1d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 1d arrays with boolean values, that looks like

```
array_in = np.array([False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False])
```

This arrays have different length. As you can see, there are parts, where True values located next to each other, so we have groups of Trues and groups of Falses. I want to count the number of True groups. For our case, we have

```
N = 2
```

I tried to do some loops with conditions, but it got really messy and confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [np.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to determine changes between groups. By attaching `False` to the start and the end of this difference calculation we make sure that `True` groups at the start and end are properly counted.

```
import numpy as np

array_in = np.array([False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, True])

true_groups = np.sum(np.diff(array_in, prepend=False, append=False))//2

#print(true_groups)
>>>4
```

Comment: Your result is 4, not 2

Comment: Because this input array is different.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write loops and conditions, you could take a shortcut by looking at this like a connected components problem.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure

array_in = np.array([False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False])
N = max(measure.label(array_in))
```

When an array is passed into the measure.label() function, it treats the 0 values in that array as the "background". Then it looks at all the non-zero values, finds connected regions, and numbers them.

For example, the label output on the above array will be `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]`. Naturally, then doing a simple max on the output gives you the largest group number (here it's 2) -- which is also the same as the number of `True` groups.

Comment: Interesting view on the problem. How does it work?

Comment: When an array is passed into the `measure.label()` function, it treats the 0 values in that array as the "background". Then it looks at all the non-zero values, finds connected regions, and numbers them. For example, the label output on the above array will be [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]. Naturally, then doing a simple `max` on the output gives you the largest group number (here it's 2) -- which is also the same as the number of True groups.

Comment: Care to add this to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In native numpy, a vectorised solution can be done by checking how many times `F` changes to `T` sequentially.

For example,

```
np.bitwise_and(array_in[1:], ~array_in[:-1]).sum() + array_in[0]
```

I am computing a bitwise and of every element of the array with it's previous element after negating the previous element. However, in doing so, the first element is ignored, so I am adding that in manually.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way of finding the number of groups of `True` is by counting the number of `False`, `True` sequences in the array. With a list comprehension, that will look like:

```
sum([1 for i in range(1, len(x)) if x[i] and not x[i-1]])
```

Alternatively you can convert the initial array into a string of `'0'`s and `'1'`s and count the number of `'01'` occurences:

```
''.join([str(int(k)) for k in x]).count('01')
```