# Get number of keys matching a value in itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have lists of binary values and I am trying to get the number of groups of consecutive 1s in each list.

Here's a few examples:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 0
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> 1
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] -> 1
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] -> 2
```

I use itertools.groupby() to split the lists into groups, which gets me an iterator with the keys and groups, but I can't quite figure out how to get the number of groups of 1s specifically.

Obviously, I could iterate over the keys and count up with an if statement but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, having the keys `0` and `1`, you can omit the `k == 1` check and include the zeros in the sum.

`sum(k for k, _ in groupby([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]))` -> `2`

Comment: Also quite obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 1):

While writing the question, I found the following solution (which was obvious in retrospect).

```
run_count = sum(k == 1 for k, g in itertools.groupby(labels_sample))
```

I'm not sure if it's the best, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not with `groupby`, but to possibly answer the "a better way", this appears to be faster:

```
def count_groups_of_ones(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    count = 0
    while 1 in it:
        count += 1
        0 in it
    return count
```

Benchmark results for your four small lists:

```
  3.72 ms  with_groupby
  1.76 ms  with_in_iterator
```

And with longer lists (your lists multiplied by 1000):

```
984.32 ms  with_groupby
669.11 ms  with_in_iterator
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNbbsIwEPz3KfYHYVOLJqVCFRJn6AEQikJwiEVsp85GiNNTPxISoLX8Ec/szu7OKs0VK6NXX4293Y6ihIvEKjtZ0zWHK61bZBsC7liBndXQdoqeoTQWzhwykBqmoYyQu4TUmURhczR2IiMRtuDxgAWoMJ32aBJel0rWAlKvLDHmjEFvW0jvUBJjpt2FKEJKaxSgVMJVk6oxFl1AI3KMjC@PxtTtQPYjRLYwdS0KlEbf@aP46URkTRNHGiinpU4CnSKP1b9LV7/TResm2sWJJobyEZn4w8k@GncQuqhUbs@0li22HHSnDsL23jVWaqTzWugTVu1mzmGh8oa6N4cQz6KhfjthNTbXJ0FXbLTRU747z4YuR8ofvwYlNY1u0TpXh2O@ifNTX8vnDMU4JGzocNs3yuC9Rx50@85n6@VHCaqFOcyAIiwgFWun4VWXWaZzJbKMkccs5j8JCTXvnu4SV/317qO/u5TDH3dgk0f8KTd5odLIuh39Y19sdPFsECMv@0wTd6b4zv0G3gcHh@X4pxMP4XsOnwm73X4B)):

```
def with_groupby(lst):
    return sum(k for k, _ in groupby(lst))

def with_in_iterator(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    count = 0
    while 1 in it:
        count += 1
        0 in it
    return count

from timeit import repeat
from itertools import groupby
from collections import deque
from operator import itemgetter, countOf

funcs = [
    with_groupby,
    with_in_iterator,
]

def benchmark(lists, number):
    print('lengths:', *map(len, lists))
    for _ in range(3):
        for func in funcs:
            t = min(repeat(lambda: deque(map(func, lists), 0), number=number)) / number
            print('%6.2f ms ' % (t * 1e6), func.__name__)
        print()    

lists = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
]

for func in funcs:
    print(*map(func, lists))
benchmark(lists, 10000)
benchmark([lst * 1000 for lst in lists], 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that is more general:

```
def count_groups(lst, value):
    start = object()
    return sum((a is start or a != value) and b == value for a, b in zip([start] + lst, lst))

count_groups([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 1) # 2
```

If optimizing for speed over a long list, try adapting [this answer that uses `numpy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390015/how-to-count-groups-of-certain-value-in-a-numpy-1d-array):

```
def count_groups(lst, value):
    return np.diff(np.array(lst) == value, prepend=False, append=False).sum() // 2
```

Comment: Could chain as `a != value == b`.

Comment: And [not safe](https://tio.run/##VU67CsIwFN3zFUdcEuwguIjQxW9wKyWkbVojaRLzEPTna/pw8AwX7j2v697xbs3p7Pw0tVqEgKv1w4Ugo5M9OJdPzmmQui@QaTUqLaLs2CqZ4WVM3uDmkyRk9rQ2mcgHb5MLVIdY4CV0kptlk4c0UoFduXIQpkOD8rf21kMU@aIMPsrRyjYP2UbKahywRObBGCHZs3xMGXFemUj/yqumziGMAXscp@kL) for objects that say they equal your `object()`.

Comment: Hmm, how is `count_groups([b], b)` returning `0` expected? Surely should be `1`. Those other solutions weren't made for and announced as more general, and their straightforward generalizations [do compute `1`](https://tio.run/##fVHBbsMgDL3zFd4N1ByW9TJNymXfsFtVIZJAy0qAgdna/XxGSNatXTUfkPzs92w//An3zq4ffRhHFdwAGmVA50wEPXgXEHbBJd@eCOmMiBGeXdg9EcjRSwWcyzfOaZRGVZDLetBGoOzZ3DJFkJiChZeQJCETp3PJIi@ykdfURKzgXZgkF9JCiGmgAu6auQbC9tBC850qF0BUGdEWPrWnG9e@yg4p28IKimR@GLsx8eHfiXVRPlTAJ@Xl9onBQCs4nBe4pbz@q6wRmmJpkShQoWT0vmQfe23kclMeqPHHuLlx1UB9hoQx9HhpwnGmsd@HFCYh2a7yXZSRqVNNnZfmV1fWXOXreRkftEWq6KbdZscZG8cv).

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right. I have edited so that `count_groups([0], b)` and `count_groups([0, b, 0], b)` both return 1 (since 0 == b), consistent with behavior of `groupby`.

Comment: Yes, looks ok now. Sad that it became longer like that. I don't see a better fix, either, though.

Comment: Hmm, well, maybe a version where we [compute the comparisons first](https://tio.run/##VY69CgIxEIT7PMWATYLXiI2I11j4BHbHEXK6p4GYxPyI@vJnohY6xbLsznyMf6Szs8uVD9N0MCpGbF04rRmKjjRCSrpKySOZsUF564s2KtFRfCxVgVIOFvuQibGaObhskzwFl33kJqYGN2UyfSN0jWjR3dG2nztGF3CHtijenv0gY75whQ2Gt0U1ZSmup/a82ykTqce84po6hGBsKOBanwvmg7aJ/zXphr4QhABmWEzTCw). Takes a bit extra memory, but requires fewer value-vs-element comparisons (exactly n instead of n to 2n).