# Complex counting in order

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to locate the instances where values starting with "4." or "5." (e.g. 4.004, 5.066) appear in a column. But they sometimes appear back to back and in that case, I want to count them as one instance. When that value stands alone, I want to count it as one instance as well. So in the example data, the occurrence should be 3 times (i.e. "4.006 and 5,003", "4.003" and "5.009, 4.069, 4.005").

```
import re

data = """
0.222
4.006
5.003
0.993
4.003
0.006
5.009
4.069
4.005
0.344
"""


matches = re.findall(r'(?:4\.|5\.)+|(?:4\.|5\.)', data)

occurrences_count = len(matches)

print(f"Total occurrences: {occurrences_count}")
```

I want to use the first, second and last occurrence later as an index so I need to know the order. Therefore, counting the consecutive ones and individual ones separately and adding them doesn't work. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks very much.

Comment: What's wrong with a loop?  Seems like the only issue here is that you're trying to be fancy.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to approach this is to convert your string into a numpy array first like below and use numpy operations to answer your question:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([float(x.replace(",", ".")) for x in data.split("\n") if len(x)])
arr
```

Print:

```
array([0.222, 4.006, 5.003, 0.993, 4.003, 0.006, 5.009, 4.069, 4.005,
       0.344])
```

Then you can mask your array for `>=4` and `<=6` and use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65391012/6385519) to count the groups of Trues:

```
arr = (arr >= 4) & (arr <= 6)
np.sum(np.diff(arr, prepend=False, append=False))//2
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop through the rows would do the job.
If you need also the indexes of the rows you could add those to a nested array.

```py
data = """
0.222
4.006
5.003
0.993
4.003
0.006
5.009
4.069
4,005
0.344
"""

instances = []
current = []
for i, row in enumerate(data.split()):
    if row[0] in ("4", "5"):
        current.append(i)
    elif current:
        instances.append(current)
        current = []

print(f"instances: {len(instances)}")
print(instances)
```

Would give you:

```
instances: 3
[[1, 2], [4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: I ended up using this one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear this was helpful for you, @RenTremendous. Could you please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be done with a regex:

```py
import re

data = """
0.222
4.006
5.003
0.993
4.003
0.006
5.009
4.069
4.005
0.344
"""

# Match one or more lines starting with 4 or 5 and a period.
matches = re.findall(r'(?:^[45]\..*?\n)+', data, re.MULTILINE)
occurrences_count = len(matches)
print(f"Total occurrences: {occurrences_count}")
```

Output:

```
Total occurrences: 3
```

> [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I'm trying to locate the instances where values starting with "4." or "5." (e.g. 4.004, 5.066) appear in a column. But they sometimes appear back to back and in that case, I want to count them as one instance. When that value stands alone, I want to count it as one instance as well.  ...'*

A basic *loop* should suffice.

First, divide the text, for each line.
Then, traverse the values, appending each, until a non-associative value, or the last item, is encountered.

Here is an example.

```py
import math as m
D, d, f = [], [], 0
for v in data.split():
    if m.floor(f := float(v)) in [4, 5]:
        d.append(f)
    elif d:
        D.append(d)
        d = []
if d: D.append(d)
```

Output

```
[4.006, 5.003]
[4.003]
[5.009, 4.069, 4.005]
```

> *'... I want to use the first, second and last occurrence later as an index so I need to know the order. Therefore, counting the consecutive ones and individual ones separately and adding them doesn't work. ...'*

You could, additionally, retain the corresponding index, from *data*.
Either *character* index, or *line number*.

```py
import math as m
D, d, f = [], [], 0
for i, v in enumerate(data.split()):
    if m.floor(f := float(v)) in [4, 5]:
        d.append((i, f))
    elif d:
        D.append(d)
        d = []
if d: D.append(d)
```

Output

```
[(1, 4.006), (2, 5.003)]
[(4, 4.003)]
[(6, 5.009), (7, 4.069), (8, 4.005)]
```